# Is the DeBroglie wavelength and uncertainity in its position same thing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I was wondering that if I have a wave then most accurately I can define its position would be its wavelength. So the uncertainty in position would be the wavelength and from deBroglie's equation we can find the wavelength of matter. So shouldn't be wavelength of a particle always equal to uncertainty in its position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Just one wavelength gives you just one frequency (according to DeBroglie's dispersion relation) and thereby, a plane wave, (if all the components are moving in the same direction) which is maximally delocalised. Dispersion in position has to do with *how widespread in different wavelengths* (frequencies) your state is. IOW, it's not how big or small your wavelength is, but how blurred your state is in different wavelengths. In terms of frequencies, it's to do with *group velocity,* rather than with *phase velocity.*